# There are multireasons the [multifile] tag should be burninated

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [multifile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multifile) tag has no wiki information and has 82 questions.  Every question has at least one other tag.  It hasn't been used much recently (no questions in the last 30 days; about a quarter of those asked are unanswered).  All the top answerers have only answered one question; all the top askers have only asked one question.

There isn't much consistency about when the tag is used beyond 'multiple files' are involved somehow.  Sometimes it's multiple source files to build a program; sometimes it's multiple files to be uploaded (but there's also the tag [multifile-uploader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multifile-uploader) that should be used for that, with no tag wiki and 271 questions); sometimes it's about processing multiple files at runtime.  It covers a wide range of languages.

The tag doesn't really provide useful information about the question.

In 2019, the [multiple-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-files) tag was burninated according to [rm -rf ./* gets rid of [multiple-files]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386436/rm-rf-gets-rid-of-multiple-files).  That was a better tag name than [multifile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multifile).

---

#### Burninate questions

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   It qualifies the questions a little, but not usually in a way that's crucial.  To the extent that multiple files are involved, it is unambiguous; however, how those files are involved varies a lot, and is somewhat ambiguous.
2. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   No.
3. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   Processing multiple files is on-topic but doesn't really warrant being singled out.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   Rather loosely, yes.  Mostly no.

---

#### Summary

All in all, I think the [multifile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multifile) tag should be burninated.  What say you?

Comment: Given that more than 24 hours have passed with only positive reactions, I plan to start removing the [tag:multifile] tag from questions using it.  Thank you for your support.

Comment: I've removed the [tag:multifile] tag from all the questions with the tag, updating the question content for some but by no means all of the questions.  The tag should be cleaned up later today as it is unused.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think most users use tags to quickly identify what a question is about, and like you said, the [multifile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multifile) tag doesn't really tell me enough at a glance to be as useful as other tags such as [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session) or even [ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipad).

It works badly as an informative tag on a single question because it's not instantly clear in what way the tag relates to the question at hand without reading the actual question anyway. In my opinion, it works even worse as a search parameter since the tag is so broad that you can't really tell what you'll get back.

You have my blessing.